Hola buenos dias, trato de correr el codigo pero me aparece este error
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError


    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:524)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:554)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:428)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:393)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:27)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)
    at Vista.Login.<init>(Login.java:16)



/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Vista;

import Modelo.LoginDAO;

/**
 *
 * @author Ryzen
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Login lg = new Login();
    LoginDAO login = new LoginDAO();
    
    
    private static Login log(String correo, String pass) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
    public void validar (){
        
        String correo = txtCorreo.getText();
        String pass = String.valueOf(txtPass.getPassword());
        if (!"".equals(correo) || !"".equals(pass) ){
        
            
            
            lg = Login.log(correo, pass);
            
            if (lg.getCorreo() != null && lg.getPass() != null){
                Sistema sis = new Sistema ();
                sis.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
                        
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtCorreo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtPass = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Img/Img/iniciar.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel3.setText("Correo Electronico");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel4.setText("Password");

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 0, 0));
        jButton1.setText("INICIAR");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 3, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Img/Img/facebook.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Siguenos en ");
        jLabel5.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 204));

        jLabel6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Img/Img/instagram.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Siguenos en ");
        jLabel6.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtCorreo)
                            .addComponent(txtPass)
                            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 176, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(96, 96, 96)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 107, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(118, 118, 118)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(txtCorreo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(txtPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(320, 10, 330, 380));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));

        jLabel7.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Img/Img/Logo Lomito.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 0));
        jLabel8.setText("Experiencia, Calidad y Servicio");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 322, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(0, 112, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 165, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 460, 400));

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Img/Img/login ac.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 0, 670, 400));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Login().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCorreo;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtPass;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private Object getCorreo() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private Object getPass() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}


Puede ser que haya alguna llamada recursiva

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Hola Cesar, bienvenido, la linea Login lg = new Login(); crea un hermoso bucle infinito, ya que cuando instancias la clase, esta intenta crear un nuevo Login que intenta crear....
